# Insert line in InfluxDB using CURL

Tags: curl, influxdb

I have the following POST request which is done from C#:

```
POST http://192.168.123.27:8086/write?db=HWDB HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Host: 192.168.123.27:8086
Content-Length: 97
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

HARDWARE,CPU=1 count=91i 1456298998307783936
HARDWARE,CPU=2 count=92i 1456298998307783936
```

I want to do the same request using CURL. I'm using the following command:

```
curl -i -XPOST http://192.168.123.27:8086/write?db=HWDB --data-binary "HARDWARE,CPU="1" value=91, CPU="2" value=92 1422568543702900257"
```

This will return the error:

```
{"error":"unable to parse 'HARDWARE,CPU=1 value=91i, CPU=2 value=92i 1422568543702900257': invalid field format"}
```

How should I change the CURL command to work? I'm running CURL from Windows, if I use:

```
curl -i -XPOST http://192.168.123.27:8086/write?db=HWDB --data-binary "HARDWARE,CPU=1 value=91"
```

data is correctly inserted in DB. Also tried to insert from file using the example from InfluxDB documentation:

```
curl -i -XPOST http://192.168.123.27:8086/write?db=HDWB --data-binary @data.txt
```

This will return:

```
{"error":"partial write:\nunable to parse 'cpu_load_short,host=server02 value=0.
67\r': invalid number\nunable to parse    'cpu_load_short,host=server02,region=us-w
est value=0.55 1422568543702900257\r': bad timestamp"}
```

Content of data.txt:

```
cpu_load_short,host=server02 value=0.67
cpu_load_short,host=server02,region=us-west value=0.55 1422568543702900257
cpu_load_short,direction=in,host=server01,region=us-west value=2.0 1422568543702900257
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding the `data.txt` file, Windows is the key factor here. It is almost certainly introducing a CRLF rather than just a linefeed at the end of the lines. See the [InfluxDB docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/troubleshooting/frequently_encountered_issues/#getting-an-unexpected-error-when-sending-data-over-the-http-api) for more.

As for the direct example at the top of your post:

```
curl -i -XPOST http://192.168.123.27:8086/write?db=HWDB --data-binary "HARDWARE,CPU="1" value=91, CPU="2" value=92 1422568543702900257"
```

the content is not [valid line protocol format](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/write_protocols/line/) and can never work. Each point must be on a new line, and values cannot be shared between points. Stripping out the `curl` syntax, this is the attempted write:

```
HARDWARE,CPU="1" value=91, CPU="2" value=92 1422568543702900257
```

And this is the actual valid syntax:

```
HARDWARE,CPU="1" value=91 1422568543702900257
HARDWARE,CPU="2" value=92 1422568543702900257
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/

```
<measurement>[,<tag_key>=<tag_value>[,<tag_key>=<tag_value>]] <field_key>=<field_value>[,<field_key>=<field_value>] [<timestamp>]
```