# influxDB bulk insert using curl

Tags: curl, influxdb

influxDB and curl

Referred to this link and managed to insert 1 row into influxDB [Insert line in InfluxDB using CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596542/insert-line-in-influxdb-using-curl)

1. Have ensured that my csv does not contain carriage returns
2. Have ensured that there is a separate row for each data point/ measurement

Sample CSV: 
test A=0,B=0,C=0.02,D=0
test A=0,B=0,C=0.02,D=0

Curl command: 
curl -i -XPOST http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb --data-binary @data3.csv

Any clues please? Thanks

Comment: Running into issues while doing bulk insert    {"error":"unable to parse 'teststat A=0,B=0,C=0.02,D=0.1\rteststat A=0,B=0,C=0.02,D=0.1\rteststat A=0.1,B=0.2,C=0.02,D=0.1\rteststat A=0,B=0,C=0.02,D=0.1\rteststat A=0.2,B=0,C=0.02,D=0.1\r': invalid number"}

Answer (score 1):

```
'teststat A=0,B=0,C=0.02,D=0.1\rteststat A=0,B=0,C=0.02,D=0.1\rteststat A=0.1,B=0.2,C=0.02,D=0.1\rteststat A=0,B=0,C=0.02,D=0.1'
```

Should be

```
'teststat A=0,B=0,C=0.02,D=0.1\nteststat A=0,B=0,C=0.02,D=0.1\nteststat A=0.1,B=0.2,C=0.02,D=0.1\nteststat A=0,B=0,C=0.02,D=0.1\n'
```

replace the `\r` with `\n`

Comment: any way to push data without re-specifying "tags" every line?