# Writing terminal output from slurm sacct command into influxdb using curl post?

Tags: curl, post, influxdb, slurm, sacct

I need to send the data that the slurm sacct command provides into influxdb using the curl command. I continuously get a

> 400 cannot parse error

returned from influx.

Answer (score 0):

400 error code means, you sent a request that InfluxDB server could not understand. Check your command. Refer some successful stories around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596542/insert-line-in-influxdb-using-curl) to find something to learn.